# XSL concatenation by tag

Tags: xml, xslt, concatenation

If I have below XML

```
<Set>
<Row>
  <DBNAME>X</DBNAME>
  <ID>1</ID> 
</Row>
 <Row>
  <DBNAME>X</DBNAME>
  <ID>2</ID> 
</Row>
 <Row>
  <DBNAME>Y</DBNAME>
  <ID>1</ID> 
</Row>
 <Row>
  <DBNAME>Y</DBNAME>
  <ID>4</ID> 
</Row>
</Set>
```

and I need to convert to this format.

```
<RESULTSET>
    <RESULT>
    <DBNAME>X</DBNAME>
    <ID>1,2</ID>
    </RESULT>
    <RESULT>
    <DBNAME>Y</DBNAME>
    <ID>1,4</ID>
    </RESULT>
</RESULTSET>
```

What do I need to do. 
Currently without condition of DBNAME I can do something similar to

```
<ID>
<xsl:for-each select="Set">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="ID"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
                ,<xsl:value-of select="ID"></xsl:value-of>
       </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</ID>
```

which give me `<ID>1,2,1,4<ID>`

Thank you for helping!

Comment: This is a grouping problem. Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 here? In XSLT 1.0 you would use a technique called Muenchian Grouping do this. In XSLT 2.0 you could make use of the **xsl:for-each-group** function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grouping, [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) with XSLT 1.0 and with XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:template match="Set">
  <RESULTSET>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Row" group-by="DBNAME">
      <RESULT>
        <xsl:copy-of select="DBNAME"/>
        <ID><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/ID" separator=","/></ID>
      </RESULT>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </RESULTSET>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Anyways to do this in 1.0 instead?

Comment: Later used a solution from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/278747/Grouping-in-XML-elements-using-XSLT-version